# Permutations not working

Tags: python, permutation

i have a simple problem that i want to work out. here it is:

([][][]/[][][]) + ([][]/[][]) = 1

the aim is to make the statement above true with the digits 0-9 and each number can only be used  once. also each part of the sum is equal to a half. e.g. (1/2)+(1/2)=1

i have started it off but it doesn't seem to work
.
this is the code that i have started

```
from itertools import permutations

target = 1

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in permutations(range(0,10), 10):
    m = ((100*a + 10*b + c)/(100*d + 10*e + f)) #works out first half of sum
    n = ((10*g + h)/(10*i + j)) #works out second half of sum
    value = m + n #works out the answer
    if value == target and (bool(m) == bool(1/2)) and (bool(n) == bool(1/2)): # checks if answer = the target and makes sure both parts of the sum are equal to a half
        print("{}{}{}/{}{}{} + {}{}/{}{} = {}".format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,target)) #prints out the answer
```

my outcome when running this is a blank prompt just waiting and then nothing appears and the prompt closes.

i also get the same response when running it through the python IDLE. it waits and the console doesn't detect any errors.

which says that there isn't a problem with my functions but something with the for loop is wrong and i cant seem to find the fault

why doesn't it work and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What do you mean 'why doesn't it work'? How are we supposed to show you how to fix it if we don't know exactly what is going wrong, your expected output etc...?

Comment: sorry let me edit it. wait a minute

Comment: it is intended to check wether the first half of the sum is equal to a half as the problem is that both sides of the sum are equal to a half    @unutbu

Comment: If both n and m are required to be 0.5, what is the purpose of asking for a target from the user? By definition, the only possible target is 1. Or should I take this to mean n and m must be 0.5 * target?

Comment: @AMacK you are absolutely right i will edit my code now

Comment: @AMacK i meant only 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If using Python2, add

  ```
  from __future__ import division
  ```

  to use floating point division. Otherwise `1/2` equals `0`. This also
  affects the calculation of `m` and `n`, since all the inputs are ints
  but you want `m` and `n` to be floats.
- If using Python3,

  ```
  target = input("what number do you want to reach? ")
  ```

  is a bug, since `input` returns a `str`. You need `target` to be a
  float (or, as DSM points out, a Fraction):

  ```
  target = float(input("what number do you want to reach? "))
  ```
- `bool(m)==bool(1/2)` is a bug. Without floating point division, `bool(1/2)` is equal to `bool(0)` which is
  `False`. With floating division, then `bool(1/2)` is `True`, but
  `bool(m)==bool(1/2)` would then be testing that `bool(m) == True`.
  That would be `True` for any floating point value for `m` other than 0.
  Instead, to check if `m` is equal to `target/2`, use

  ```
  abs(m - target/2) < eps
  ```

  for some tolerably small value of `eps`.
  Do not use `m == target/2` because checking floats for equality may fail
  due to the inexactness of the floating point representation of real
  numbers.

---

```
from __future__ import division
from itertools import permutations
eps = 1e-8
target = float(input("what number do you want to reach? "))

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in permutations(range(0,10), 10):
    m = ((100*a + 10*b + c)/(100*d + 10*e + f)) #works out first half of sum
    n = ((10*g + h)/(10*i + j)) #works out second half of sum
    value = m + n #works out the answer
    if value == target and abs(m - target/2) < eps and abs(n - target/2) < eps: # checks if answer = the target and makes sure both parts of the sum are equal to a half
        print("{}{}{}/{}{}{} + {}{}/{}{} = {}".format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,target)) #prints out the answer
```

yields

```
what number do you want to reach? 1
067/134 + 29/58 = 1.0
069/138 + 27/54 = 1.0
073/146 + 29/58 = 1.0
079/158 + 23/46 = 1.0
079/158 + 32/64 = 1.0
093/186 + 27/54 = 1.0
135/270 + 48/96 = 1.0
138/276 + 45/90 = 1.0
145/290 + 38/76 = 1.0
148/296 + 35/70 = 1.0
185/370 + 46/92 = 1.0
186/372 + 45/90 = 1.0
267/534 + 09/18 = 1.0
269/538 + 07/14 = 1.0
273/546 + 09/18 = 1.0
293/586 + 07/14 = 1.0
307/614 + 29/58 = 1.0
309/618 + 27/54 = 1.0
327/654 + 09/18 = 1.0
329/658 + 07/14 = 1.0
351/702 + 48/96 = 1.0
381/762 + 45/90 = 1.0
451/902 + 38/76 = 1.0
481/962 + 35/70 = 1.0
485/970 + 13/26 = 1.0
485/970 + 16/32 = 1.0
485/970 + 31/62 = 1.0
486/972 + 15/30 = 1.0
```

Comment: what is the big deal about eps = 1e-8?

Comment: what does it do i do not understand @unutbu

Comment: Type `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` into a Python interpreter. It will return `False`. This is [not a bug in Python](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm). It is a problem in all systems that use IEEE754 floating point arithmetic. Because of this difficulty, you need to be aware that comparing floats for **equality** can lead to unexpected results. The standard workaround is to compare the **nearness** of floats with each other. That is what `abs(m - target/2) < eps` is doing. If `m` is near `target/2`, then the expression is `True`.

Comment: @unutbu: I think you may need to relax your condition somewhat.

Comment: @DSM: Please explain?

Comment: @unutbu: ah, sorry.  I completely missed the "each part must be 1/2" condition, and so I thought you were missing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Several things I spot off the bat.

1. `target` is still a string - it needs to be converted
2. `m`, `n`, and `1/2` may be using integer division (depending on your python version) i.e., they truncate to floor(val1/val2)
3. I'm not certain, but I'm pretty sure you need to index the `{}`s in your print statement. If it does work like that, I've never seen it.
4. `bool(val)` in the case of integers and floats is always True except for 0. You'll need to change this
5. Just in case - be wary of floating point error - `value` and `target` may very well not be equal. You'll likely need to round to be sure. The same goes for checking that m and n == 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have already pointed out the bugs, so I'll only add that since Python already has a `Fraction` class, you might as well use it:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from itertools import permutations

# python 3
target = Fraction(input("what number do you want to reach? "))
# (in Python 2, use raw_input)

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in permutations(map(Fraction, range(0,10)), 10):
    m = (100*a + 10*b + c)/(100*d + 10*e + f)
    n = (10*g + h)/(10*i + j)
    value = m + n
    if value == target:
        print("{}{}{}/{}{}{} + {}{}/{}{} = {}".format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,target)) #prints out the answer
```

which gives

```
dsm@winter:~/coding$ python3 permtarg.py
what number do you want to reach? 1
024/138 + 57/69 = 1
027/189 + 54/63 = 1
028/146 + 59/73 = 1
032/184 + 57/69 = 1
...
```

Update: oops, I didn't catch the "each part must also be 1/2" condition.  But that's trivially handled by adding `and m == n == Fraction(1, 2)`.

Comment: I think the OP wants `m` and `n` to equal `1/2`, but I'm not sure since the OP comments that this works...

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating all permutations of digits 0-9 is 10! == 3.6 million iterations.  However, with the restrictions that each term must equal a half, and only each digit can be used once, we can cleverly reduce the workload.

So, for a/b + c/d = 1, where b has 3 digits, b must be even, and have unique digits, so must be one of:

```
b_candidates = [i for i in range(2,1000,2)  
                   if len(set('{:03}'.format(i))) == 3]
```

len(b_candidates) = 360

If we further restrict it by a = b // 2 and all digits of a and b must be unique

```
b_candidates = [i for i in range(2,1000,2)  
                   if len(set('{:03}{:03}'.format(i,i//2))) == 6]
```

len(b_candidates) == 75

Performing similarly for d, we get

```
d_candidates = [i for i in range(2,100,2) 
                   if len(set('{:02}{:02}'.format(i,i//2))) == 4]
```

len(d_candidates) == 27

Now, we only have 75*27 == 2025 items to compare.

```
answers = ['{:03}/{:03} + {:02}/{:02}'.format(b//2,b,d//2,d) 
            for b in b_candidates for d in d_candidates 
             if len(set('{:03}{:03}{:02}{:02}'.format(b//2,b,d//2,d))) == 10]

['067/134 + 29/58',
 '069/138 + 27/54',
 '073/146 + 29/58',
 '079/158 + 23/46',
 '079/158 + 32/64',
 '093/186 + 27/54',
 '135/270 + 48/96',
 '138/276 + 45/90',
 '145/290 + 38/76',
 '148/296 + 35/70',
 '185/370 + 46/92',
 '186/372 + 45/90',
 '267/534 + 09/18',
 '269/538 + 07/14',
 '273/546 + 09/18',
 '293/586 + 07/14',
 '307/614 + 29/58',
 '309/618 + 27/54',
 '327/654 + 09/18',
 '329/658 + 07/14',
 '351/702 + 48/96',
 '381/762 + 45/90',
 '451/902 + 38/76',
 '481/962 + 35/70',
 '485/970 + 13/26',
 '485/970 + 16/32',
 '485/970 + 31/62',
 '486/972 + 15/30']
```

Answer (score 0):

i was actually experimenting and realise that all i really needed was to change from bool() to float()

```
from itertools import permutations
target = 1
x = 0

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in permutations(range(0,10), 10):
    m = float((100*a + 10*b + c)/(100*d + 10*e + f)) #works out first half of sum
    n = float((10*g + h)/(10*i + j)) #works out second half of sum
    value = float(m + n) #works out the answer
    if value == target and float((100*d + 10*e + f)/2) == float(100*a + 10*b + c) and float((10*i + j)/2) == float(10*g + h) :
        x = x + 1
        print("{}{}{}/{}{}{} + {}{}/{}{} = {}".format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,target)) #prints out the answer

print("there were {} answers".format(x))
```